# Getting InvalidProtocolBufferException while running oozie job

Tags: oozie

I'm getting the below exception while running the sample oozie examples.
I've modified the job.properties located at the /examples/apps/map-reduce with the appropriate nameNode and jobTracker details.
I'm using the below command to run the oozie job:
"sudo oozie job -oozie http://ip-10-0-20-143.ec2.internal:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run"

Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Failed on local exception: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag.; Host Details : local host is: "ip-10-0-20-143.ec2.internal/10.0.20.143"; destination host is: "ip-10-0-20-144.ec2.internal":50070;

The hadoop core-site.xml also has the correct proxyuser details for oozie user.

Really, dont know where it is going wrong?? :(

Answer (score 2):

I will answer in case someone will google up this page.
In my case the cause was in using http address for Name Node.

You should check your job configuration and if there stays something like:

```
nameNode=yourhostname:50070
```

You should change it to something like this:

```
nameNode=hdfs://yourhostname:8020
```

Check your ports first of course!

Please notice that jobTracker parameter has different notation. In my case it's:

```
jobTracker=yourhostname:8021
```

and it works fine.
Hope it helps to someone.